# NSMutableArray cannot remove duplicates

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sorting, nsmutablearray, duplicates

I have duplicates in my array and i want to get rid of them, so i run this loop, however it doesn't work. Any one know why?
The array currently has 3 items, 2 duplicates and 1 unique.

```
 for (int x = 0; x <= [array count]; x++) {
    if(x > 0){
        if([[array objectAtIndex:x - 1] isEqualToString:[array objectAtIndex:x]]){
            [array removeObjectAtIndex:x];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't iterate over an object and modify it at the same time. Once you remove an object, the indexes of all the objects change. You can try copying the array first and iterate that and make the modifications in the original array, but you still might have to change some of your logic depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm only ever compares items that are next to each other in the array (the items at positions `x` and `x-1`). If the duplicates are in any other positions, they won't be found.

The naïve way to fix this is to do a double loop. Compare each item in the array with every item after it. This will start taking an extremely long time as your array becomes bigger.

The correct way to do this is to let the framework handle the operation. Convert your array to a set (which does not have duplicates by definition) and then back to an array:

```
NSSet * s = [NSSet setWithArray:array];
NSArray * dedupedArray = [s allObjects];
```

If you need to preserve the order, you'll have to do this in a slightly roundabout way, although this is still faster than the double-loop:

```
NSMutableSet * itemsSeen = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableArray * dedupedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for( id item in array ){
    if( ![itemsSeen containsObject:item] ){
        [itemsSeen addObject:item];
        [dedupedArray addObject:item];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simply using NSSet ( or NSMutableSet ). It will automatically ensure you have only one of every object.

BUT - notice it is one of every OBJECT. It can have 2 objects that are different but have the same inner value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that there are no duplicates in your array, it would be better to use an `NSMutableSet` rather than an `NSMutableArray`.

`NSMutableSet` maintains the invariant that every object in the set is unique.

For example:

```
NSMutableSet* set = [NSMutableSet set];
NSString* data = @"Data";
[set addObject:data];
[set addObject:data];
```

The second call to `addObject:` will do nothing as data is already in the set.

Comment: The key difference is that an array is ordered, which may be important if the data are to be displayed, e.g., in a table.